# Flag overview in chat should be more detailed and have filters

Tags: feature-request, flags, chat, moderator-tools

Moderators can look up which posts of a particular user were flagged in chat. This is very useful to quickly get some history on a user when handling a situation in chat. Because chat moderation is global on SE chat, quite often the moderator dealing with the situation is not familiar with the history of the users causing problems. Looking at the chat flags is a quick way to get see if the user has a history of misbehaving.

The problem with the flag report is that it doesn't really distinguish between validated and dismissed flags. So it can also be filled with spurious flags that were dismissed. This makes it harder to find the important flags that were validated and resulted in message deletion and suspension of the user.

The report should ideally indicate

- if the flag was validated or declined
- whether a mod was involved
- how many users validated or invalidated the flag

I'd also like to have the ability to filter for validated/invalidated/all flags, with the default on validated flags.

Comment: Yes please. This would also help catch users who flag to annoy others.

Comment: @Manishearth My proposal only covers the "flags received" part, not who is flagging. While that would also be nice, I think there is already a feature request on that

Comment: Ah, I misread "how many users validated" as "which users validated". My bad.